# Why do you say "schiacciare un pisolino"?

Tags: idioms

In a blog on Italian language to which I subscribe the writer used the idiom "schiacciare un pisolino". I love to know how language comes about and am very curious to know why one would squash a little nap. Does anyone know the origin of this term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*"Pesolo"*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pesolo/) is from latin *"pēnsĭlis"*, hanging. It was used by Dante Alighieri in the Divine Comedy ([Inferno, XXVIII](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/a/alighieri/la_divina_commedia/html/testo_01.htm)):

> E ’l capo tronco tenea per le chiome
>
> Pesol con mano a guisa di lanterna

[*"Pisolino"*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pisolino/) is diminutive of [*"pisolo"*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pisolo/), derived from [*"pisolare"*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pisolare/) and this from *"pesolo"*. The image is that of a heavy head, reclining, due to drowsiness. Note that these are all associated with *"pensum"*, supine of *"pendĕre"*, *"to measure"*, whence *"peso"*, *"weight"*. Curiously *"pennica"* is from *"pendicare"*, similar in etymology to *"pisolare"*.

Agnolo Bronzino (1503-1572) used *"stiacciare un sonnellino"* in [*"Rime in burla. Lo spedale"*](http://ww2.bibliotecaitaliana.it/xtf/view?docId=bibit001679/bibit001679.xml&chunk.id=d7186e15873&toc.depth=1&brand=bibit):

> E dopo desinare un sonnellino
>
> puoi stiacciare e poi desto trattenerti
>
> con qualche altro malato tuo vicino.

According to [Ivana Palomba](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/03-03-2009/schiacciare_un_pisolino-1212404.html), a user of Giorgio De Rienzo and Vittoria Haziel's forum *Scioglilingua* of *Il Corriere della Sera*, the origin of this expression can be found in the Florentine goldsmith tradition (!) where molten gold was removed from the mould and left to rest. They used the verb "*stiacciare*" to indicate the molten gold resting and solidifying (*"stiacciare"* is Florentine for Italian *"schiacciare"*). This happened at night, and in the meantime the goldsmith went to … squash a little nap.

I have no idea where Palomba got this interpretation and whether or not it is a reliable source: it seems a bit elaborate, but quite plausible. Anyway, I wasn't able to find a better source.

Comment: Grazie mille @randomatlabuser Come al solito Lei ha dato una risposta molto interessante alla mia domanda.